# saving a graphic file

Tags: c#, graphics

I am creating a Form Application and in this Application I let the user Draw Rectangles, Triangles,Hexagon etc. I want to save those graphics in a file and I want to use them when I open the program.I mean use them like nirmal graphics. I am selectingand changing the color of the drawn objects i wan to.be able to change the color of it if I import this file into my application

Comment: Alright, sounds like a plan to me.

Comment: Create a bitmap and draw into that, then save it.

Comment: Either draw into a bitmap or draw onto a control, like a Panel or PictureBox __in its Paint event with the e.Graphics object__ and then use DrawToBitmap and save the result..

Comment: I changed my question that is not a duplivated question I looked around for hours for my question

Answer (score -1):

Somthing like this.

```
// write
BinaryWriter Writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(FileName, FileMode.Create));;

Writer.Write(this.Point.X); Writer.Write(this.Point.Y); Writer.Write(this.Point.Z);
Writer.Write(this.Point.X); Writer.Write(this.Point.Y); Writer.Write(this.Point.Z);  
Writer.Write(this.Point.X); Writer.Write(this.Point.Y); Writer.Write(this.Point.Z);
Writer.Write(this.Point.X); Writer.Write(this.Point.Y); Writer.Write(this.Point.Z);    

Writer.Flush();
Writer.Close();

// read
BinaryReader Reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(FileName, FileMode.Open));

this.Point.X = Reader.ReadDouble(); this.Point.Y = Reader.ReadDouble(); this.Point.Z = Reader.ReadDouble();    
this.Point.X = Reader.ReadDouble(); this.Point.Y = Reader.ReadDouble(); this.Point.Z = Reader.ReadDouble();    
this.Point.X = Reader.ReadDouble(); this.Point.Y = Reader.ReadDouble(); this.Point.Z = Reader.ReadDouble();    
this.Point.X = Reader.ReadDouble(); this.Point.Y = Reader.ReadDouble(); this.Point.Z = Reader.ReadDouble();

Reader.Close();
```